# App in virtual directory but /Folder points to www.app.com/

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, mvc

I am looking to create a virtual directory to host a demo of an application. the app is written in asp.net mvc and the images/css etc point to /Content/images /Content/main.css etc.

when the app is in the main directory everything is fine. when i create a virtual directory (say www.app.com/admin) then the images and css point to www.app.com/Content/images etc.

Is there any way to make the resources be relative to the virtual directory? thx

My host uses dotnetpanel

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first slash from the path. The first slash make it an absolute path.

**Update to comment:** From the point of view of the app user the current directory is:   www.app.com/admin
so the path: "Content/main.css" will be added to it and the result will be:
www.app.com/admin/Content/main.css
Which is the path you want.

Try it.

**Update 2:** The url is not relative to where we are "looking" but to the place it is declared from. So if you have to get from:
www.example.com/categories/new/somthing.html
to
www.example.com/admin/Content/main.css
the path should be:
../../admin/Content/main.css

Comment: but then it will be relative to the current folder. if i am looking at home/action and i select profile/user it will go to home/action/profile/user

Comment: will give it a try and lets hope its that simple

Comment: as expected it doesnt work. if the css is linked to Content/css/main.css then this is relative to the current "directory". if we are looking at www...com/categories/new then the css is relative to that